# Limit: $2^{\frac{(-1)^n - n}{n}}$as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate this lim $2^{ \frac{( - 1 ) ^n - n}{n}}$as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

I know that the final answer is 1/2. but I do not know how.could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\lim 2^{\frac{(-1)^n-n}{n}} = \lim 2^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-1}. $$
One more thing: notice that when $n$ is even the exponent becomes $\frac{1}{n}$, whereas if $n$ is odd you get $-\frac{1}{n}$. In any case, $\lim \pm \frac{1}{n} = 0$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Start by pulling the expression apart:
$$
2^{\frac{-n+(-1)^n}{n}} = 2^{-1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}=2^{-1}2^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}=\frac122^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}
$$
Now for all $n>1$, $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \leq \frac1n$ so 
$$2^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}} 2^{\frac1n}
$$
So for sufficiently large $n$, $2^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}$ is arbitrarily close to  $2^0 = 1$ so the limit you want is 
$$
\frac12 \cdot 1 = \frac12
$$